# What is the best estimator when factors have high colinearity?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am working on a predictive model for some real estate marketing business

```
y~f(X)
```

the problem is that my X has significant colinearity. This problem comes from the fact that a lot of raw features are 'naturally' correlated. For example, the average household income in a zip code is correlated with the education level in that zip code : people went to college tend to make more money.

I am thinking about removing the highly co-linear factors. However, I am afraid that by doing so I am going to throw away a lot of valuable information.

Ideally, is there any prediction (other than OLS) that works well with colinear factors? Is decision tree a good choice here?

Any insights here?

Thanks

Comment: See also: [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52177/what-to-do-with-collinear-variables)

Comment: You might look into [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or other forms of [factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis).

Comment: If it is co-relations you are looking to analyze maybe Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA) could perform better than PCA, but quite difficult to tell without data to test on.